# xcode ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, clang, debug-symbols

I am making a game in xcode and c++ with GLUT & OpenGL. I want to place a 3D model in my game and this is the general look of the header file:

```
unsigned int GunNumVerts = 37812;

float GunVerts [] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
 0.266494348503772, 0.0252334302709736, -0.000725898139236535,
0.265592372987502, 0.0157389511523397, -0.000725898139236535,
0.264890836474847, 0.0182004476109518, -0.00775888079925833,}
float GunNormals [] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
0.986904930120225, -0.0937549933614904, -0.131257990706016,
0.986904930120225, -0.0937549933614904, -0.131257990706016,
0.986904930120225, -0.0937549933614904, -0.131257990706016,}
float GunTexCoords [] = {
// f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
0.110088, 0.229552,
0.108891, 0.243519,
0.119508, 0.240861,}
```

I am getting this error with it:

```
duplicate symbol _GunNumVerts in: /blah/blah/blah/Mouse.o
/blah/blah/blah/ViewPort.o
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am trying to display this in my display method in my viewport as follows:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, GunVerts);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, GunNormals);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, GunTexCoords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, GunNumVerts);
```

I have 7 other duplicate symbol little phrases but there is only one actual error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined your variables in the header. That way each variable is present in every (8) compilation units. Instead *declare* the variables in the header and *define* them in a .cpp file.

For example:

```
// Gun.h:
extern unsigned int GunNumVerts;
extern float GunVerts[9];


// Gun.cpp:
unsigned int GunNumVerts;
float GunVerts[9] = {
    // f 1/1/1 1582/2/1 4733/3/1
    0.266494348503772, 0.0252334302709736, -0.000725898139236535,
    0.265592372987502, 0.0157389511523397, -0.000725898139236535,
    0.264890836474847, 0.0182004476109518, -0.00775888079925833};
```

`extern` tells the compiler that the adress of the variable is resolved later (by the linker).
Also, if you never intend to change these values at runtime they should be declared as `const`.

/Edit: since you are using clang which has a very good C++11 support, you could also use `constexpr` for these values. Then they only reside in the header. However, understanding the linker is important for a C++ developer so the original advice stays.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help as it fixed my issue but now I'm getting an issue of "Excess elements in array initialiser" in each of the floats. How would I fix this?

Comment: Most likeley you messed up the number of elements. `float a[42] = {1, 2};` won't work.

Comment: Oh jeez, theres thousands and I used a .pl in terminal to give me the number of vertexs and such. Thank you for helping me with the issue.

Comment: `std::vector` is your friend