# What is the meaning of following linker error in C++ program using g++

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, g++

What does the following linker error message mean?

I have used the following steps to compile my project. However at the end I am getting the linker error.

```
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -c Action.cpp 
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -c Space.cpp 
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -c Player.cpp
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -c Pieces.cpp
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -c GameBoard.cpp 
guest-wireless-upc-nat-206-117-88-027:PA4 Rafael$ g++ -g -Wall -o  game game.cpp        
GameBoard.o Space.o Player.o Pieces.o Action.o
```

Error:

```
duplicate symbol _a in: 
     /var/folders/ds/t3m3drzx7yjc78gh8xfyf73r0000gn/T/game-0a62a1.o GameBoard.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It probably means you declared a variable or function named `a` in a header and are including that header in multiple files.  Hard to do other than guess since you didn't post any code.

Comment: possible duplicate: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576245/xcode-ld-8-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: To be precise, that would not be a *declaration*, but a *definition*. It is perfectly fine to *declare* the symbol in many translation units as long as it is defined in at most one.

Comment: I like how when you read the error message and it says "duplicate symbol _a" and then you look for what it said was duplicated (_a) and ... there's more than one of them defined!  Amazing!  Sad though that it had to be asked.  We're doomed.

Comment: I'm new to programming. But, I think the doom is still warranted, because the world has people who have the time and interest to post such comments as you do - thumbs up, loser.