# Xcode duplicates -- ld: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, xcode

I have researched a little bit on stackoverflow and so far, this question: [xcode ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576245/xcode-ld-8-duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64) gets close to answering the question I have, but the solution did not work for me.

Therefore I am posting the problem here (I will leave out what I am guessing are the irrelevant parts).

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include "Header.h"
#include "functions.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string word;
string inText;
vector<string>wordArray;

cout << "Input text: " << endl;
//Get any size of input from user
getline(cin, inText);
cout << "getline input: " << inText;

AppliedFunctions applFunction;

leastFreqLetter = applFunction.getLeastFreqLetter(inText);

cout << "leastFreqLetter is: " <<     
leastFreqLetter << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Header.h

```
//  Compiler: XCode and Dev-C++

#ifndef Assignment_1_Header_h
#define Assignment_1_Header_h

#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Variable declarations...

class AppliedFunctions
{
    void AppliedFunction()
    {
        return;
    }

    public:
        void countWordFreq(string inputText);

        char getLeastFreqLetter(string inText);

        string getMostFreqWord(string textArray[], int length);
};

    class Letter
    {
        public: 
            char letterVal;
            int freq;
            //Constructors
            Letter();
            Letter(char);

            void setVal(char);
    };

//Default constructor
Letter::Letter()
{
    letterVal = '0';
}

//Constructor
Letter::Letter(char value)
{
    letterVal = value;
}

(...)

extern Letter currLetter;


#endif
```

functions.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include "Header.h"

(variable initializations...)

char AppliedFunctions::getLeastFreqLetter(string inputText)
{
    //Method body
}
```

When I try to compile and run main.cpp in Xcode 6.4 I get the following error message:

```
ld: 38 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see      
invocation)
```

One example of duplicate symbols:

```
Build/Intermediates/Assignment 1.build/Debug/Assignment     
1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/functions.o
duplicate symbol _currLetter in:

/PATH_TO_XCODE_FOLDER/DerivedData/Assignment_1-
ercdhboeobtkrkgyggpfqkbzqnlj/Build/Intermediates/Assignment 
1.build/Debug/Assignment 1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

/PATH_TO_XCODE_FOLDER/DerivedData/Assignment_1-
ercdhboeobtkrkgyggpfqkbzqnlj/Build/Intermediates/Assignment 
1.build/Debug/Assignment 1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/functions.o
```

I figured that there are duplicates of (in this case) the variables currLetter found in main.o and functions.o respectively. Therefore I tried turning the #include "functions.cpp" in main.cpp into a comment together with anything that uses the AppliedFunctions class in the same file. This did reduce the amount of registered duplicates from 38 to 5 but if I turn the above mentioned parts above into comments then main.cpp cannot "see" the functions I want to test in the main method such as getLeastFreqLetter().

I have also tried to run the same project in Dev-C++ on windows 7 and I encountered the exact same error messages. I also do not have the -ObjC flag set under Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags.

I apologize for the inconvenience in advance. I am sure that the solution is straightforward and that I am just failing to see the obvious.

Specifications:
XCode: Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Compiler in XCode (if the name in the error log is the right one): clang

Dev-C++: 4.9.9.2

Comment: You don't ever include source files (`.cpp`), only header files (`.h`). Why did you include it?

Comment: Remove `#include "functions.cpp"` and properly fix the issues you run into. You'll need to add `inline` to the member functions you've defined in the header.